# parse JSON with GSON returns null

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Here is my Json :

```
[
{
"canaldsc":"PHARMA",
"cadenadsc":null,
"formatodsc":"DEL AHORRO",
"estadodsc":null,
"ciudaddsc":"VALLE DE MEXICO",
"regiondsc":"CENTRO SUR",
"proyectotiendaid":null,
"proyectoid":"79",
"planid":"54",
"proyectodsc":"Concurso",
"vigencia":"0000-00-00",
"activo":"1",
"usuarioproyectotiendaid":"65280",
"proyecto":null,
"fechainicio":"2014-03-24",
"lunes":"7",
"martes":"7",
"miercoles":"7",
"jueves":"7",
"viernes":"7",
"sabado":"7",
"domingo":"7"
},
{
"canaldsc":"PHARMA",
"cadenadsc":null,
"formatodsc":"DEL AHORRO",
"estadodsc":null,
"ciudaddsc":"VALLE DE MEXICO",
"regiondsc":"CENTRO SUR",
"proyectotiendaid":null,
"proyectoid":"79",
"planid":"54",
"proyectodsc":"Concurso",
"vigencia":"0000-00-00",
"activo":"1",
"usuarioproyectotiendaid":"65284",
"proyecto":null,
"fechainicio":"2014-03-24",
"lunes":"7",
"martes":"7",
"miercoles":"7",
"jueves":"7",
"viernes":"7",
"sabado":"7",
"domingo":"7"
}
]
```

In reality, there is more than 2 objects, but I cut it to simplify

My Model Class :

```
public class PdvResult {
public PdvResult() {
}

public String canaldsc;
public String cadenadsc;
public String formatodsc;
public String estadodsc;
public String ciudaddsc;
public String regiondsc;
public String proyectotiendaid;
public String proyectoid;
public String planid;
public String proyectodsc;
public String vigencia;
public String activo;
public String usuarioproyectotiendaid;
public String proyecto;
public String fechainicio;
public String lunes;
public String martes;
public String miercoles;
public String jueves;
public String viernes;
public String sabado;
public String domingo;
}
```

It should be corresponds in the names so that the mapping can happen.

In my Java, I use

```
List<PdvResult> pdvs = (List<PdvResult>)gson.fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<PdvResult>() {}.getType());
```

but pdvs return null.

What's wrong with my code????

Comment: Your `TypeToken` is incorrect. It should have a type argument of `<List<PdvResult>>`.

Comment: I changed it, but still give me null ! - it's also giving me a warning in this line : Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to List<PdvResult>

Comment: Can you change the JSON definition ??? I would add a name to the array value. Like { "pdvs": [ {...}, {...}] }

Comment: I've done it, but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line where you parse the JSON, use this:

```
List<PdvResult> pdvs = gson.fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<List<PdvResult>>() {}.getType());
```

You are using `TypeToken<PdvResult>`, and you have to use `TypeToken<List<PdvResult>>`, otherwise you're trying to parse your JSON into a `PdvResult` object, while you actually have an array of `PdvResult` objects!

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis already told me this, but it's not working. Guess I will parse it without Gson !

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro, are you getting any Exception? Otherwise I'd suggest you to check your `reader`, maybe for some reason you're not reading the JSON correctly, so you're getting `null`...

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro, really weird... And are you sure your JSON is EXACTLY like what you wrote, it starts and ends with `[ ... ]` and contains only a number of equal objects `{ ... }`?

Answer (score 0):

The best way of checking the type of returned JSON object is explained below:

- Start form `Object` class

  ```
  Object result= gson.fromJson(reader,Object.class);
  System.out.println(result.getClass().getName());
  ```
- It will return `java.lang.ArrayList`
- Do the same operation of `ArrayList`

  ```
  System.out.println(((ArrayList)result).size());
  System.out.println(((ArrayList)result).get(0).getClass().getName());
  ```
- Now it will print the name of class stored in `ArrayList`
- Repeat the same operation till leaf nodes
- Finally form the resultant JSON object as expected by inspecting object and class type

Comment: I am using `com.google.gson.Gson` and its working fine for me. What are you using.

Comment: My output is `java.util.ArrayList
2
com.google.gson.internal.StringMap`

Comment: Here is my rest code : `Reader reader=new FileReader(new File("resources/abc.txt"));
        Gson gson=new Gson();
        Object result= gson.fromJson(reader,Object.class);`