# Encoding A Java Object (POJO) into a JSON String in GWT

Tags: java, json, gwt, json-rpc, resty-gwt

## Objective

I'd like to use JSON-RPC to send this on the clientside:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"RegisterValues","params":[["Planets","Stars"]],"id":2}
```

## My Attempt

Using Resty-GWT:

```
public interface testService extends RestService {

    @Produces("application/json")
    @POST
    public void myCall(Params myparams, MethodCallback<Response> callback );

    public class Params {
          String jsonrpc = "2.0";
          String method;
          //String[] params;
          Map<String, String> params;
          int id;

          public void setId(int id){
              this.id = id;
          }

          public void setMethod(String method){
              this.method = method;
          }
                          }

          public void setParams(Map<String, String> params){
              this.params = params;
          }

        }
```

When I call upon the Params object in another class (to set up the call), doing something like this:

```
Map<Integer, String> myParams = new HashMap<Integer, String>(); 
myParams.put(0, "Planets");
myParams.setParams(myParams);
```

Obviously this then sends it like:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"RegisterValues", "params":{"0":"Planets"}, "id":0}
```

I can't figure out how to get those magic: `[["Planets"]]`

I tried using a `String[]` but this gives me the result: `["Planets"]`

`String[][]` gives the error that it isn't supported yet.

## Horrible Hack

If I pass a `String` in my `testService` as:

```
String myparams = "{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\"RegisterValues\",\"params\":[[\"FPlanets\"]],\"id\":2}";
```

It works but obviously this is horrible.

I tried using GSON to encode the POJO, but GWT doesn't allow reflections. I tried using [thetransactioncompany](http://software.dzhuvinov.com/json-rpc-2.0-base.html) to parse the object into a 'String' but couldn't figure out the `<inherits>` I needed in my `gwt.xml` file.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
List<List<String>> params;
```

instead of

```
Map<String, String> params;
```

in your `Params` POJO class.

Read my post here about [How to create a POJO class structure from an JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22720966/parse-json-with-gson-returns-null?answertab=votes#tab-top).

---

below JSON string

```
"params":[["Planets","Stars"]]
```

represents a `List<List<String>>` where "params" is a variable name in your POJO.

POJO:

```
class Params implements Serializable {
    private String jsonrpc;
    private String method;
    private int id;
    private List<List<String>> params;
    ...
   //getter/setter
   //default constructor
}
```

Try this one at server side

```
String myparams = "{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\"RegisterValues\",\"params\":[[\"FPlanets\"]],\"id\":2}";
Params params=gson.fromJson(myparams,Params.class);
System.out.println(params.params+"-"+params.id);
```

Send the `Params` object back to client.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed and well laid out answer